# Sinking streamed data into Parquet files / Convert Java Stream into Spark's DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, java-stream, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am reading data from some API into a Java Stream of a custom class (A). Currently I am sinking this data into CSV files, but I want to change these files into Parquet files. The data is divided into multiple files based on an attribute (i.e. grouped based on that attribute). Is there an easy (recommended) way to achieve this using Spark or from the Java Streams directly?

The data may get very large (up to 20 GB) so I can not simply collect it as a list and then write it in one batch. It should be sinked.

I was thinking of converting the stream into Spark's DataFrame and then writing this DataFrame into a Parquet file. If this could help me giving the large size of the data, could you please let me know how to convert a Java Stream into Spark's DataFrame? If not, please suggest another way to achieve this.

My current code looks something like this (I have simplified the code to be readable):

```
Stream<A> data = apiService.getData();
data.forEach(instance -> {
  // This function simply returns an instance of a custom class that takes care of sinking the data into a CSV file.
  // The file is selected within the function based on a single attribute's value of the data instance.
  getTheAppropriateSinkFor(instance).add(instance);
});
```